# ASP.NET Auditing - Using a system.webServer module

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an `ASP.NET MVC` cloud service and I have a requirement to audit any request coming to my server, whether it is authenticated or not.

I would like to log all requests and their responses before it gets to the actual controller that handles them.
This was it is transparent to any developer in my team and I can assure no one forgets to audit requests in case of API additions as it's not up to them.

Is `system.webServer` `modules` the right way for accomplishing that?
What are the best practices for accomplishing such a thing?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may consider creating an action filter and register it globally so that it will be executed for all the requests.

```
public class AuditLoggingFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        // Do something
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }    
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
       // Do something
    }
}
```

`OnActionExecuting` will be executed before the action method is invoked and  `OnActionExecuted` will be called after the action method is invoked.

Now in your `RegisterRoutes` methods (inside *`RouteConfig.cs`*), you can register this filter globally.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
   //Existing code
   GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new AuditLoggingFilter());
}
```